# How to pass two parameter to sa_sigaction? they are FILE* and PID of child process

Tags: c, linux

When I capture any signal, I want to send message 'end' to child process and if they still live use kill pid to kill it. NO global variable

I think I have to use sa_sigaction, but I confuse how to send FILE* of pipe and pid of child to it. Can someone can give em an example for this??

I'd like to pass pip and pid to hdl how to change my code??
I'd like to capture all signal that can be captured, what is the first parameter
of  sigaction(SIGINT, &act, pip) ?? instead of just SIGINT
Thanks in advance

```
static void hdl (int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *pip)
{
    xxxxxxx
}

int main() {
    FILE** pip;
    int* pid;
    struct sigaction act;
    memset (&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = &hdl;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, pip);


    sleep (10); 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your program doing?

Comment: its a game, I just confuse how to terminate the child process when parent receive a signal. I seem allow to use global variable. but I still confuse how to capture all signal, because sigaction(SIGINT, &act, pip) can capture SIGINT only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply **not possible** (to pass more arguments to a signal handler). You need to use some global or static variable.

<sup>You cannot add any parameter to your signal handler, even as simple as a `pid_t` or `FILE*` or some `void*`</sup>

Signals are delivered by the kernel, and it is the kernel (with some help from some low-level, machine and ABI specific, [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29)-like code in the `libc`) which pushes a call frame for the signal handler (and also one for [sigreturn(2))](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html). So the signature of handlers is fixed, as documented in [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Besides, you have a small number of signals. So you could consider having a global variable with an array of data related to the signal.

With [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) (using `SA_SIGINFO`) you get an `int` signal number, a `siginfo_t` and a `ucontext_t` pointers to your handler. You can use them appropriately. For instance, for a `SIGIO` you can use the `si_fd` to get the file descriptor causing that signal.

Beware that *signal handlers are only allowed to call* (even *indirectly*) a very *small set of functions* (the so-called **async-signal-safe** functions, which are often a subset of [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)). In particular calling `fputs` or any `<stdio.h>` function; or `malloc` is *forbidden* inside signal handlers. Hence, even thru some global variables, you should not use any `FILE*` inside your signal handler (that would be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), even if it might apparently work as you want sometimes).

A common habit (see POSIX documentation about [signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html)) is to *only* set some  global `volatile sig_atomic_t` flags in the signal handler, and to test (and reset) that flag *outside* the handler. You'll then be able typically to call [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) -probably using [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html)- or [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) (*outside* of yous signal handler, e.g. in some loop inside your main code).

You need to reads books on [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and or *Advanced Posix Programming*

Comment: Is it possible that just pass one parameter pid or FILE??? I pretty confuse how to use the third parameter of sa_sigaction Thanks

Comment: No, it is not possible. And you cannot use `FILE*` inside your signal handler. The only sensible thing to do in your case is to set some global `volatile sig_atomic_t` variable in your signal handler.

Comment: got it thank you, one more question: I want to handle all signal (not sigkill and sigstop), but sigaction(SIGINT, &act, pip) just handle SIGINT, how to set the sigaction or I have to write 20+ sigaction???

Comment: Did you RTFM [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) & [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) ? And STFW for them?